# WinXP keyboard shortcut to page left/right

Tags: windows-xp, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there such keyboard shortcut can do page left/right? Or any 3rd party tools? The reason ask this is because when coding or debugging, there are too many chances need to read very long message, but I'd prefer not to wrap text. Thanks.

EDIT: what if for the case when viewing webpage, and the line extends outside the boundary? I know all mentioned methods, but it's still too slow, I am looking for scrolling a page at a time. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) script will make Alt+Page Up and Alt+Page Down work like "page left" and "page right" in some programs.

```
!PgUp::
  ControlGetFocus, control, A
  SendMessage, 0x114, 2, 0, %control%, A
return

!PgDn::
  ControlGetFocus, control, A
  SendMessage, 0x114, 3, 0, %control%, A
return
```

For example, the script works for me in Windows XP Notepad, Wordpad, Visual Studio Express 2008, and Internet Explorer 7. The script doesn't work for me in OpenOffice.org 2.3, Chrome 4.0, Firefox 3.0, and Opera 10.01. (Although Opera already has Ctrl+Page Up and Ctrl+Page Down keys built-in for page left and right.)

Comment: I noticed something in common among the programs that this script works on. If you right-click on the scroll bar, you'll get a context menu with items like Scroll Here, Left Edge, Right Edge, Page Left, Page Right, Scroll Left, Scroll Right. Thus, you can check for a scroll bar context menu to predict if this script will work with a program.

Comment: I can't get the following to work in W7.  Do you know if the commands have changed?

Comment: Ignore the last comment.  I just can't get the following to work `+^AppsKey::
   ControlGetFocus, control, A
   SendMessage, 0x114, 2, 0, %control%, A
Return`

Answer (score 1):

You could get a mouse that supports horizontal scroll.

Or if you really want a keyboard shortcut, you can use <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Left</kbd> / <kbd>Right</kbd> to move a word at a time, which is faster then plain <kbd>Left</kbd> / <kbd>Right</kbd> but more granular then <kbd>Home</kbd> / <kbd>End</kbd>.

Comment: most mice do support horizontal scroll - the middle mouse button will enable this

Answer (score 0):

The 'Home' and 'End' keys will take you to the beginning and end of the line, respectively. This will only work if the cursor is on the line that extends past the screen boundaries.